# Find squares of even and odd numbers in the given list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list `L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` and I want to find the squares of all even numbers in `L` and the squares of all odd numbers in `L`.

For example, `L = [2, 4, 6, 8]` should give `[4, 16, 36, 64]`, and `L = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]` should give `[1, 9, 25, 49, 81]`.

I have tried it like this, but I'm not able to get lists as a result:

```
num=input("enter the number:")
# num=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
if (num%2==0):
    print "The number is even"
    print num*num
else:
    print "The number is odd"
    print num*num
```

Answer (score 1):

This longs for list comprehension, but you cannot since there are 2 target lists (well you could but that would mean testing evenness twice).

So define 2 output lists, and loop through the input list selecting one or the other list using a ternary expression, so you perform a sole `append` (more elegant)

```
L1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

even_sq,odd_sq = [],[]

for i in L1:
    (even_sq if i%2==0 else odd_sq).append(i*i)

print(even_sq,odd_sq)
```

result:

```
[4, 16, 36, 64] [1, 9, 25, 49]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the list using a for loop, check if each number is even or odd, and then append the square of each num to the correct list:

```
odd_squares = []
even_squares = []
for num in L1:
    if (num % 2) == 0:
        even_squares.append(num ** 2)
    else:
        odd_squares.append(num ** 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions to achieve what you want:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
even_squares = [e * e for e in L if e % 2 == 0]
odd_squares = [e * e for e in L if e % 2 != 0]
print(odd_squares, even_squares)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 9, 25, 49] [4, 16, 36, 64]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Jean-François' solution, but avoids the ternary expression, by indexing the appropriate list directly:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

def even_odd_squares(l):
    r = [[], []]

    for ll in l:
        r[ll%2].append(ll*ll)

    return r

even, odd = even_odd_squares(L)
print(even, odd) # [4, 16, 36, 64] [1, 9, 25, 49]
```

Answer (score 0):

is This okay?

```
def get_even_odd_squares(no_range):
    even_squares, odd_squares = [], []
    for no in no_range:
        if no % 2 == 0:
            even_squares.append(no ** 2)
        else:
            odd_squares.append(no ** 2)
    return even_squares, odd_squares  # ([4, 16, 36, 64], [1, 9, 25, 49, 81])
```